# Calculation of $A'(0)$ (first variation of the area functional).

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm trying to do the calculation that shows that a surface in $\Bbb R^3$ is area minimizing if and only if the mean curvature is zero. I'm getting a sign wrong and I'm going crazy, I need help.

Notations: Fix a domain $D$. Here ${\bf x}$ is a parametrization, ${\bf x}^t = {\bf x}+t{\bf V}$ is a variation, with ${\bf V}$ being zero on $\partial D$, $\bf N$ is the normal unit vector and $A(t)$ is the area of ${\bf x}^t$.

So far, I have $$A'(0) = \iint_D \langle {\bf N}, {\bf x}_u \times {\bf V}_v + {\bf V}_u \times {\bf x}_v \rangle \,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v,$$ and I'm positive that so far, so good. Then, the trick seems to use Green-Stokes with $P = \langle {\bf N}, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_u\rangle$ and $Q =  \langle {\bf N}, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_v\rangle$.

$$\begin{align} \frac{\partial Q}{\partial u} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial v}  &= \langle {\bf N}_u, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_v\rangle+\langle {\bf N}, {\bf V}_u\times {\bf x}_v\rangle+\langle {\bf N}, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_{uv}\rangle \\ &\qquad -\langle {\bf N}_v, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_u\rangle-\langle {\bf N}, {\bf V}_v\times {\bf x}_u\rangle-\langle {\bf N}, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_{uv} \rangle \\ &= \langle {\bf N}_u, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_v\rangle-\langle {\bf N}_v, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_u\rangle + \langle {\bf N}, {\bf x}_u \times {\bf V}_v + {\bf V}_u \times {\bf x}_v \rangle\end{align}$$

Now let's look only at: $$\begin{align} \langle {\bf N}_u, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_v\rangle-\langle {\bf N}_v, {\bf V}\times {\bf x}_u\rangle &= \langle {\bf V}\times{\bf x}_v, {\bf N}_u\rangle  - \langle {\bf V}\times{\bf x}_u,{\bf N}_v\rangle \\ &=  \langle {\bf V},{\bf x}_v\times {\bf N}_u\rangle  - \langle {\bf V},{\bf x}_u\times{\bf N}_v\rangle  \\ &= \langle {\bf V}, {\bf N}_v\times{\bf x}_u+{\bf x}_v\times{\bf N}_u\rangle \\ &= -2H\langle {\bf V},{\bf x}_u\times{\bf x}_v\rangle,\end{align}$$ using that $${\cal S}{\bf v}\times{\bf w}+{\bf v}\times{\cal S}{\bf w} = 2H {\bf v}\times{\bf w},$$ where ${\cal S}$ stands for the shape operator, with ${\bf v} = {\bf x}_v$ and ${\bf w}={\bf x}_u$. The line integral that appears after using Green-Stokes is zero because $\bf V$ is zero in $\partial D$ and we get: $$A'(0) = 2\iint_D H \langle {\bf V},{\bf N}\rangle \,{\rm d}A.$$ But all books say that $$A'(0) = \color{red}{-}2\iint_D H \langle {\bf V},{\bf N}\rangle \,{\rm d}A.$$
Where is the mistake?

Comment: Ivo, you might as well correct the typo in the shape operator line, while you're at it. Oh, and say that $\mathcal S$ stands for the shape operator.

Comment: Hi Ted. Ok. And you mean pointing the mistake in the question too?

Comment: Oh, nevermind, I just saw it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh crap, I believe I found it. In fact, we have $${\cal S}({\bf x}_u) = \color{red}{-}{\bf N}_u, \quad \text{and}\quad {\cal S}({\bf x}_v) = \color{red}{-}{\bf N}_v,$$which yields $$\begin{align} {\bf N}_v\times{\bf x}_u+{\bf x}_v\times{\bf N}_u &= -{\cal S}({\bf x}_v)\times{\bf x}_u+{\bf x}_v \times(-{\cal S}({\bf x}_u)) \\ &= - ({\cal S}({\bf x}_v)\times{\bf x}_u+{\bf x}_v \times{\cal S}({\bf x}_u)) \\ &= - 2H\,{\bf x}_v\times{\bf x}_u \\ &= 2H\,{\bf x}_u\times{\bf x}_v, \end{align}$$ and then stuff proceeds smoothly. I decided to post this as an answer instead of deleting the question - you never know if someone might find this useful someday.

Comment: I think posting as an answer here is a good thing!  Question *and* answer ***endorsed!!!***