# Second Variation of Area Functional

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is a follow up question from [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1273538/calculation-of-a0-first-variation-of-the-area-functional/1273556#1273556). I have proved that given a parametrized surface ${\bf x}$, the mean curvature is zero if and only if it is a critical point of the area functional. Then everybody starts handwaving and says that the surface is a minimum point. I want to check that indeed this is the case (mainly because I'll have to redo the calculations in Minkowski space where we also have maximum surfaces, and if I know how to do this here, I can adapt the calculations).

That being said, I am **not** interested in heavy machinery from Riemannian geometry.

My notation will be the same as in the other question. For your comfort:

> Notations: Fix a domain $D$. Here $\bf x$ is a parametrization, ${\bf x}^t={\bf x}+t{\bf V}$ is a variation, with $\bf V$ being zero on $∂D$, $\bf N$ is the normal unit vector and $A(t)$ is the area of ${\bf x}^t$.

Assume $H = 0$. I have computed: $$A''(0) = \iint_D \frac{2\langle {\bf x}_u\times{\bf x}_v,{\bf V}_u\times{\bf V}_v\rangle + \|{\bf x}_u\times{\bf V}_v+{\bf V}_u\times{\bf x}_v\|^2}{\|{\bf x}_u\times{\bf x}_v\|^3}\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}v$$

I can add the computations I made to get this, if it comes to that. Theory says that we must have this integral being **positive**. I don't know how to proceed here. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

---

**Edit:** rephrasing: I want to check that $\bf x$ is a local minimum of the functional. After the comments, I'm not even sure if we'll really have ${\cal A}''(0) > 0 $ then. I need this specific question adressed too. (I'm not sure I even know calculus anymore haha)

---

**Edit (05/12):** It is of my understanding that if we have a closed contour $\Gamma \subset \Bbb R^3$, then off all surfaces that have $\Gamma$ as boundary, the one that minimizes area has $H = 0$. However, having $H = 0$ does not imply that the surface is area minimizing, as pointed by several people in the comments. Ok. Let's say I am dealing only with a parametrized surface ${\bf x}: D \subset \Bbb R^2 \to {\bf x}(D)\subset \Bbb R^3$. Then the boundary would be just ${\bf x}(\partial D)$. If I consider all the variations ${\bf x}^t$ defined as above, then all of them share the same boundary as $\bf x$. Although ${\bf x}(D)$ may not be the surface having ${\bf x}(\partial D)$ as boundary that minimizes area, I am thinking so far that *between all the* ${\bf x}^t$, *at least*, $\bf x$ is the one that gives least area. With this in mind, I wanted to check that ${\cal A}''(0) > 0$.

Comment: I doubt if this is true: (Minimal surface imply $A''(0) \ge 0$)

Comment: Why? :) ${}{}{}$

Comment: There are indeed quite a lot of that: http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-994-seminar-in-geometry-fall-2004/projects/18994.pdf (BTW, just learnt a good way to write short reply in the comment, thanks ^^)

Comment: Oh crap. I can't argue with that. By the way, thanks for the link, I didn't knew that ocw.mit had material on DG. I'll talk to the professor about this, then. I'll leave the question there, anyway, Maybe someone can do some magic on that integral in the meanwhile.

Comment: @Ivo: As shown by examples in the PDF file John linked, the sign of $A''(0)$ can be negative (at a surface with $H \equiv 0$) for some variations. (For sufficiently small domains $D$, I believe $A''(0) \geq 0$ for all variations.) The classic example is the seam of a baseball, which bounds a piece of Enneper's surface, although Enneper's surface is not locally area-minimizing for that boundary curve. This means there's global geometric information lurking in your integral, not merely Cauchy-Schwarz or the like.

Comment: Yes, I think that this will be complicated. I really don't know how to proceed, then. Funny, because in Minkowski space, there must be a calculation that shows the difference between maximal and minimal surfaces. I remember seeing in a thesis here the calculation using isothermic parameters, and they used some inequalities with laplacians, and theory of PDEs.

Comment: Ivo, a cool exercise (#16 on pp. 43-44 of my notes) is that in fact in general there will be two minimal catenoids with given parallel boundary circles of the same radius. Only one of them has least area.

Comment: I suggest revising this question because it's unanswerable in the current form. Surely there are lots of *unstable minimal surfaces*, i.e., those that do not minimize area. (Google the words in italic.) The premise "everybody [...] says that the surface is a minimum point" is simply not true: maybe someone you know did that, but others don't.

Comment: @Yes Thanks for the concern, I added an edit in the question, in hope of clarifying things. Ted, I'll check it, thanks to you too :)